# How to hightlight a datagrid cell in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am having a datagrid,in that i have to highlight a particular cell based on a particular condition.
Below is the code snippet.

```
if (plannedOrderDetail.ORDER_TYPE == OrderType.Emergency || plannedOrderDetail.ORDER_TYPE == OrderType.Warning)
                {

                    e.Record.FieldLayout.Fields[6].Settings.CellPresenterStyle = ApplicationEx.GetResource<Style>("HighLightCellStyle");  
                }
```

This code highlights all the cells in the 6th column.How can i highlight the particular cell.

Answer (score 1):

If `ORDER_TYPE` is accessible via the row's data context, you could use a style trigger, approximately like this:

```
<DataGrid...>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="theSixthColumn" ...>
        <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                ...
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ORDER_TYPE}" 
                                 Value="Emergency">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ORDER_TYPE}" 
                                 Value="Warning">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

First get Specific DataGridCell from DataGridRow, then apply Style.

Below is extension for get DataGridCell from row by column index:

```
    public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGridRow row, int column)
    {

        if (row != null)
        {
            DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);

            // try to get the cell but it may possibly be virtualized
            DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            return cell;
        }
        return null;
    }
```